# Delta G values for Pyruvate--> Alanine vs. Oxaloacetate -> Aspartate ->Asparagine

Tags: biochemistry, energy, free-energy, reference-request

What are the delta G values for the mammalian (human) biosynthesis of alanine from pyruvate, and for the conversion of oxaloacetate to asparagine? (assuming no particular cellular restriction or other systemic pressures like catalysis or anabolism)

I am aware that oxaloacetate must be converted to aspartate and then to asparagine.  Based on the fact there are two steps to that conversion, I assume that cumulatively the delta G value is higher for the oxaloacetate to finally get to asparagine. So I want to know how much of a difference there is in the delta G values of these two conversions.

This is NOT a homework question, it is to better my own understanding.  I would welcome peer-reviewed literature, or other resources if you deem them applicable.